# QLineEdit. Hide the beginning of long line

Tags: qt, qlineedit

I have long string into QLineEdit. The beginning of line is hide.

[image]

Line:"151051.50000000"

I want hide the end and show the beginning of line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `lineEdit->setCursorPosition(0);`
2. You can also use [`QDoubleSpinBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html) without up and down buttons for that purpose.
3. You can also use [`QString::number()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6) with limited precision:

`lineEdit->setText(QString::number(your_value, 'f', 3)); // 3 decimal places`